# WSGI Error when Trying to Deploy Web Flask App with PythonAnyWhere

Tags: python, web, flask, wsgi, pythonanywhere

I want to deploy my flask app publicly using pythonanywhere.  I am new to this (I am a beginner). I have followed all steps exactly. But I have got some error on my web flask app. On my website, I use python3.7, HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.
Here's the error message on error log:

```
2020-08-14 08:37:07,432: Error running WSGI application
2020-08-14 08:37:07,435: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
2020-08-14 08:37:07,436:   File "/var/www/analisisbipolardisorder_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>
2020-08-14 08:37:07,436:     from my_flask_app import app as application  # noqa
2020-08-14 08:37:07,436: 
2020-08-14 08:37:07,436:   File "/home/analisisbipolardisorder/mysite/my_flask_app.py", line 3, in <module>
2020-08-14 08:37:07,436:     from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
2020-08-14 08:37:07,437:
***************************************************
2020-08-14 08:37:07,437: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2020-08-14 08:37:07,438: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2020-08-14 08:37:07,438: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2020-08-14 08:37:07,439:
***************************************************
```

I really don't know how to fix that.
On my file named 'my_flask_app.py', there are some warning like this:

- 'flask.url_for' imported but unused (even though I need 'url_for' module in other file)
- 'pandas' imported but unused (even though I need library pandas to import DataFrame and read_csv module)
- 'pandas.DataFrame' imported but unused
- 'pandas.read_csv' imported but unused

And also on my WSGI file, there is a warning like this:

- 'my_flask_app.app as application' imported but unused (even though I need this to run my web flask app)

My Flask look like this (my_flask_app.py):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import csv

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    with open (r"/home/analisisbipolardisorder/css/bipolarlabelled.csv", encoding="utf8") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        dataset = [row for row in reader]
    with open (r"/home/analisisbipolardisorder/css/df_train90.csv", encoding="utf8") as train_file:
        reader = csv.reader(train_file)
        train = [row for row in reader]
    with open (r"/home/analisisbipolardisorder/css/test_prediction_9010.csv", encoding="utf8") as test_file:
        reader = csv.reader(test_file)
        test = [row for row in reader]
    return render_template('home.html', data = dataset, train = train, test = test)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And my WSGI file look like this:

```
# This file contains the WSGI configuration required to serve up your
# web application at http://<your-username>.pythonanywhere.com/
# It works by setting the variable 'application' to a WSGI handler of some
# description.
#
# The below has been auto-generated for your Flask project

import sys

# add your project directory to the sys.path
project_home = '/home/analisisbipolardisorder/mysite'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, project_home)

# import flask app but need to call it "application" for WSGI to work
from my_flask_app import app as application  # noqa
```

I really need your kind of help. Thanks before.

Comment: looks like you don't have ```pandas``` install. Install them and it will works. Ref -> [https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules/](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules/)

Answer (score 0):

1. create an environment folder. It is simple. First: `pip install virtualenv`. At second create your env: `python -m venv myenv`. If you use a Windows machine then
   `myenv\Scripts\activate.bat`, `source myenv/bin/activate` it is for
   unix/macos. Then install all your libraries here. Then do like that
   `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. if you want to disable env
   deactivate.
2. Initialize a Git

it was hard to write everything so watch this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jbdkOlf4cY) ("Deploying Flask Apps Using Python Anywhere")

Answer (score 0):

As jen pointed out in the comments, you are missing pandas
I would suggest you install a virtual environment in your project directory and then install pandas in that environment
([here is a pythonanywhere help post on that])[1](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Virtualenvs/)

If that seems too daunting, just open a bash console and type in `python3.x -m pip install pandas` the x in this code you would need to replace with the python3 version you have selected for your project (python3.8 or similar)

Let me know if you need any more information here